# Transformar varchar para float

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, matplotlib

Fiz um código que pega dados do BD para gerar um gráfico com o *matplotlib*, porém o dado no BD está como `varchar` e para a criação do dado é preciso que ele esteja no formato `float`. Como pode-se fazer a conversão?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb as mdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(plt)

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '123456', 'testdb');
null = None
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    d = cur.execute("SELECT Ping FROM Pings WHERE Enderecos = 'www.peplink.com'")
    d = cur.fetchall()

    plt.plot(d)
    plt.title("Peplink")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Não, pois o ele se apresenta depois como por exemplo "78.5 ms"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como funciona a API `MySQLdb`, mas creio que se fizer o `cast` na query deve funcionar, supondo que `Ping` seja a coluna que tem o valor do `varchar` que você citou em **formato numérico**:

```
SELECT CAST(Ping AS DECIMAL(10,6)) as Ping FROM Pings WHERE Enderecos = 'www.peplink.com'
```

Usando o `DECIMAL(10,6)`, mas pode ajustar a precisão, não tenho certeza de qual será o efeito depois de "passar" pela API.

Agora se isto não funcionar pode simplesmente pegar o resultado de `Ping` no próprio Python e fazer algo como isto:

```
 float("10.5")
```